# Django Static Files does not deploy on Google Cloud Bucket

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform

I am deploying an Django App, which runs on google server but it does not load the static files, so that App does not load the css and images.
I checked the bucket I created but there is no files in the bucket.
Here is settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = "static"

PRODUCTION = True

if PRODUCTION:
    # Define static storage via django-storages[google]
    GS_BUCKET_NAME = env("GS_BUCKET_NAME")            
    STATIC_URL = "/static/"
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage"
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = "storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage"
    GS_DEFAULT_ACL = "publicRead"
else:
    MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

Here is app.yaml file.

```
runtime: python38

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/
- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

Here is urls.py.

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

When I deploy the app, it was done successfully. but the static files does not deploy into the bucket.
As well I run this bellow command.

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

I followed [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine).

Here is structure of static directory.
[image]

Comment: What is inside your `static` directory? If you specify it in the app config, your static content (CSS and images) should be placed there.

Comment: I attached the screenshot for the structure of static

Comment: It is worth checking your Cloud Build logs, whether these folders that you shared contain any files, and add the whole file path to your `static` folder. 
Could you also clarify the end goal in this case?

Comment: I already checked the cloud logs, and the bucket too. but the static files were not upload into the bucket.